# CIVICRM won't output jQuery files

Tags: wordpress, plugins, civicrm

I have the latest version of Wordpress and CiviCRM installed and for some reason CiviCRM won't enqueue the jQuery files necessary on my custom theme but it does indeed work if I switch the custom theme to the default WP theme. How is this possible? I disabled all my plugins, functions.php file,  created a very simple page.php template (update: i even created a simple theme with just a style.css and index.php file):

```
<?php
wp_head();
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        the_content();
    //
      } // end while
} // end if
wp_footer();
?>
```

and I receive the following JS error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: cj is not defined

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like plugins>civicrm>js>jquery.conflict.js may not have run; but why I can't say. What jQuery*.js files does your new WP theme contain? CiviCRM wants to use 'cj' as an alias for jQuery.  Can you step thru in Firebug?

Comment: Heh @user990717, to improve the number of people working on CiviCRM on StackExchange we are trying to launch one specifically for CiviCRM at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm . We've got over 300 people committing to the site, but we need a few more people like yourself with over 200 reputation to also commit. Please consider how you can help yourself and others with CiviCRM interests by doing this. Thanks!